# Espaço em branco entre itens gridview.builder

Tags: flutter, dart

Meu gridView.builder está com um espaço em branco entre as linhas inexplicavel, já revirei todo o código e não tem nenhum widget com essa margin ou padding.

GridView está vindo com o espaço automático? Se sim, como faço pra remove-lo?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Meu gridView:**

```
listViewBuilderCategoriasFirebase(){
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("InfoApp")
          .doc("DadosApp")
          .collection("categorias")
          .orderBy("posicao", descending: false)
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot){

        switch(snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            //return carregandoDados;
            break;
          case ConnectionState.active:
          case ConnectionState.done:
            QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = snapshot.data;

            if(querySnapshot.docs.length == 0){
              return Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("Nenhuma categoria disponível!",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    ),),
                ),
              );
            }

            return GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                mainAxisSpacing: 0,
                crossAxisSpacing: 0,
              ),
              itemCount: querySnapshot.docs.length,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (context, indice){

                return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: (){
                      //push(context, w);
                      print("");
                    },
                    child: Text("a")
                );

              },
            );

        }
        return Container();
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

O construtor usado por você presume uma [razão de aspecto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propor%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_tela) de `1.0` para cada Widget filho do `GridView`. - Isto é, uma proporção de um quadrado - Isso pode ser visto na documentação [aqui](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html). Isso é uma característica deste Widget, para garantir a consistência entre os Widgets filhos e o cálculo de tamanho e constraints.

Ou seja, você precisa decidir *quantas* linhas simultâneas deverão aparecer em seu Gridview, e com esse valor calcular a razão de aspecto.

Um exemplo, suponha que você queira que na tela caibam 5 linhas de itens, e 2 colunas:

```
    var tamanhoDaTela= MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    /*24 é a barra de notificação no android*/
    final double alturaDeCadaItem = (tamanhoDaTela.height - kToolbarHeight - 24) / 5;
    final double larguraDeCadaItem = tamanhoDaTela.width / 2;
    final double razaoDeAspecto = larguraDeCadaItem / alturaDeCadaItem ;
```

E no final utilizar na propriedade [childAspectRatio](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount/childAspectRatio.html) do Delegate utilizado por você:

```
SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                mainAxisSpacing: 0,
                crossAxisSpacing: 0,
                childAspectRatio: razaoDeAspecto,
              ),
```

Você pode ler mais nesta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48410521/10746978) (em inglês).